# How do I configure my MongoDB to take UTF-8 into account?

Tags: mongodb, database

I want to deal with UTF-8 now. I haven't done any special configs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF8 is the encoding supported by MongoDB out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

It [supports UTF8 out of the box](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Internationalized+Strings).  There's nothing special that you need to do.