# MongoDB C Driver (UTF-8 ?)

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, mongodb-c

I have a problem of inclusion for special characters in my database (accents or Russian alphabet for example). They become unreadable/unrecoverable or create some bugs in my database.

eg. "étudier" become "tudier" / or "Наталья" will display "            ..." endlessly and will bug my base when I want to read it (from server side via db.collection.find()).

Should configure or use MongoDB somehow or the problem just comes from the languages and characters set on the machine? (MongoDB isn't supposed to handle UTF-8?)

(I use Linux distribution)

Comment: Could you provide example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905074/how-do-i-configure-my-mongodb-to-take-utf-8-into-account Mongo handles UTF-8 properly. Are you sure you provide the right data/strings/...

Comment: For the example, I edited my post. But for the encoding I finally wonder if it is not simply a mistake in Putty configuration (so it handles UTF-8) on my part... (I can not afford to test at the moment)