# Express Images With Umlauts Are not Displayed

Tags: node.js, express

I noticed that all my images with ü,ä,ö are not working on my production server. Serving locally with nodemon + browersync works fine.

What settings do I have to make to get my images displayed.

I use utf-8 in my HTML head

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="recipes">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I guess I don't have to make any settings in my mongodb:
[How do I configure my MongoDB to take UTF-8 into account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905074/how-do-i-configure-my-mongodb-to-take-utf-8-into-account)

So then I guess only the express server ("express": "^4.12.0",) needs some extra config?

The image is on the server with the name:

`niveskocht-71-grüne-speckbohnen-auf-mandel-pak-choi.jpg`

And my chrome console shows me as path:

`http://my-website/assets/images/niveskocht-71-gr%C3%BCne-speckbohnen-auf-mandel-pak-choi.jpg`

I get a 404 when trying to load the image.

EDIT:
I added this to my server.coffee:

```
app.use((req, res, next) ->
  res.charset = "utf-8";
  console.log parseurl(req).pathname
  if (parseurl(req).pathname.indexOf('login') != -1 || req.session.userType)
    next()
```

according to this:
[Node.js public static folder to serve js with utf-8 charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095347/node-js-public-static-folder-to-serve-js-with-utf-8-charset)

And I get a utf-8 header:
[image]

That is how it looks on my localhost:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a pure guess but I think it is related to, that there are diff. types or encodings of umlauts. I now just renamed all my scraped images with gulp. But this looked like it is causing a problem:

[image]

[image]