# � is showing in HTML

Tags: java, mongodb, unicode, utf-8

I am extracting some data from MongoDB and showing it to a webpage. I am using Java and Struts2 framework. Problem is, in Mongo console the letter `é`, is showing `�` this. But, Eclipse console also showing `é` . In `jsp` page, I tried with

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

but, no luck. Can anybody tell what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: i was guessing that, but what to do, from where i inserted the data, there was \u00E9 , which in utf encoding of é.

Comment: did you set encoding in java?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `meta content="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: yes, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905074/how-do-i-configure-my-mongodb-to-take-utf-8-into-account) it's showing that the default is UTF-8

Comment: Hmm my bad, I don't know why I wrote that now that I read it again. Did you already set ` meta content="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`?

Comment: If that does not work, please try UTF-16, since u00E9 is UTF-16

Comment: I'm not sure now either, it's an odd problem :/ 
Can you manually check the encoding on the webpage from the browser?